# How to include/refer existing angularjs project into another project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, bower, angularjs-controller

[image]

As mentioned in the image, Angular app1 is common module for both app2 and app3. Is it possible to inject app2 and app3 inside common module?

If it is not possible, can anyone give some idea how we can implement this?

Note: Currently i am trying to inject app2 and app3 using bower install. Is this correct?

Comment: so both app2 and app3 will use app1?

Comment: @Omar Einea Yes. Based on user selection will show app2 & app3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we have implemented this functionality using AngularJS Modularization.

Webpack is a module bundler, what does that mean? Well, it basically take modules with dependencies and generate static assets to represent those modules.

for more info:
http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/